# Delete all nested items in database when deleting a top item using MongoDB and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have three collections in my mongodb: clients, programs, and data. Data is nested in Programs and Programs are nested in Clients. That is a single client can have multiple programs and every such program can have a number of Data sets. Here is how clients' schema looks like:

```
const ClientSchema = new Schema({
  fullName: { type: String, required: true },
  dateEnrolled: { type: Date, required: true },
  isCurrent: { type: String, required: true },
  Programs: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Program' }]
});

// and my Programs schema looks like:

const ProgramSchema = new Schema({
  programName: { type: String, required: true },
  dateStarted: { type: Date, required: true },
  dateFinished: { type: Date },
  Data: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' }]
});
```

Now, when I delete a client from my database I want to delete all the programs that belong to the clients and all the data sets that were created for those programs. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
router.delete('/:clientId', (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Client.findById(id).then((client) => {
    client.Programs.forEach((programId) => {
      Program.findById(programId).then((program) => {
        Answer.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: program.Data } });
      });
      Program.deleteOne({ _id: programId })
    });
    Client.deleteOne({ _id: client._id })
  })
});
```

Comment: Nenad, thank you for your answer, but I am getting error "Cannot access 'program' before initialization"

Answer (score 0):

You can register a middleware function for `remove` in `ClientSchema`.

```
ClientSchema.pre('remove', { query: true, document: true }, async function() {
  // call deleteMany on ProgramModel
  await ProgramModel.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: this.Programs } });
});
```

You can do the same thing for `ProgramSchema` if you want to cascade delete `Answer`.

Comment: I tried, it does work when I am deleting a single program, this method does delete all nested data sets. However, when I delete a client, this method deletes all the programs but data sets related to these programs remain intact.

Comment: @Eli I updated my answer. Delete Program by `_id`.

Comment: @Eli Updated again. Set `{ query: true, document: true }` option for both `ProgramSchema.pre('remove` and `AnswerScheme.pre('remove`.

Answer (score 0):

Nenad, thank you very much, again! You gave me an idea to loop through first program ids, then through programs. My solution comes in two parts:
Part 1:

```
`router.delete('/:id', (async (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const client = await Client.findById(id);
    await client.Programs.forEach(async (element) => {
        const programs = [];
        const program = await Program.findById(element);
        programs.push(program);
        programs.forEach(async (program) => {
            await Answer.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: program.Data } });
        })
    });
    await Client.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    res.redirect('/clients');
}))`
```

part 2 that goes to Client schema file and makes sure that all the programs are deleted as well:

```
`ClientSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function (doc) {
    if (doc) { await Program.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: doc.Programs } }) }
})`
```

Now, when I delete a client all instances of related programs are deleted and all instances of data-sets related to each program are deleted, too. Thank you, guys, are all awesome!